# How do i get Text between HTML tags that have HTML inside them C#

Tags: c#, html, text, tags

```
<Item>
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>
```

i need to get this

```
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
```

using c#

i tired this

```
string startTag = "<Item>";
string endTag = "</Item>";
if (value.Contains(startTag) && value.Contains(endTag))
        {
        int index = value.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
        richTextBox1.Text = value.Substring(index, value.IndexOf(endTag) - index);
        }
```

but that only gets this

```
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</Item>Text i need
```

sorry if it is confusing but what i need is for it to get the first set if  tags at the beginning and end

Comment: You want just the text without brackets?

Comment: Is it a typo or you work with corrupted html?

Comment: Could you perhaps use JQuery?

Comment: thats just an random example but i just need to get any text in between the first set of tags using c#

Comment: </c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</c>Text i need</c>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>Text i need</Item>
</Item>Text i need</Item>

so that would be the outcome

Answer (score 0):

I think Your HTML is corrupted. There are few tools you can use to parse or get HTML from HTMl tags. Have a look at these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving your containing tag an id or class then use JQuery to get what's inside the tags like:

```
var text = $('#TagID').html();
```

or

```
var text = $('.TagClass').html();
```

You can use .text() instead of .html() if you want.